# How to upload pictures to database in WordPress and store securely via upload/submit button?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I have a form which I've created and trying to make it upload image to the WordPress database. I'm not sure if I'm going the right way about it but created an SQL database and given myself all privaleges obviously. It's a dating section of the site so don't want it to be read by anything other than those using it (I'm assuming that My SQL is secure and functions privately without being readable by bots/spiders etc?

So I have the form like so (reduced version) and it's upload submit functions

```
<b>Add Photo</b><input 
id="fileupload" name="fileupload" 
type="file" value="fileupload" /> 
<label for="fileupload"></label>. 
</div>
<div class="ur-field-item field. 
checkbox">
<p id="check_box_1555917793_field" 
class="form-row validate-required" 
data-priority=""><label 
class="checkbox required=" data- 
label="Agree">
<input id="check_box_1555917793" 
class="input-checkbox ur-frontend- 
field " 
name="check_box_1555917793" 
required="required" 
type="checkbox" 
value="1" data-rules="" data- 
id="check_box_1555917793" data- 
label="Agree" data-value="" /> 
Agree <abbr class="required" 
title="required">*</abbr></label>. 
<span class="description">I agree 
to the <a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/terms. 
and-conditions/"> Terms and 
Conditions </a> and <a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/
privacy-policy/"> Privacy Policy 
</a> of Adsler.co.uk.</span></p>
</div></div>
<button class="btn button ur- 
submit-button" 
type="submit">Submit </button>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<input name="ur-user-form-id" 
type="hidden" value="6456" />
<input id="ur_frontend_form_nonce" 
name="ur_frontend_form_nonce" 
type="hidden" value="82ebe8a59b" 
/>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- .entry-content -->
```

Ideally I'd like all content and files uploaded to Mysql to make it secure but, as I understand, Mysql doesn't handle images. So how to I do this, either by adding to WP files or another way but in any case securely?

Page:https://adsler.co.uk/dating

Answer (score -1):

Providing full working code would be a lot of work, so here ill give you a idea on how to make that:

1. you store images in /images directory of your wp-installation
2. you need php to handle the Form (since you didnt provide any php-snippet, cant be sure if you got that)(This is a good [Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) in my opinion)
3. Yeah this is secure (if the /images directory isnt public for the internet ofc)